# Can't install Ubuntu on a Dell XPS 13 9365

Tags: dual-boot, dell, ahci

Recently purchased a second hand Dell XPS 13 9365 with Windows 10.
I wiped the hard drive and attempted to install Ubuntu and some variants like Xubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, Linux Mint, Elementary.
(On my system the hard drive is a 256GB Micron NVMe SSD)
In the system BIOS the hard drive controller has 3 settings : "Disable" "AHCI" and "Raid".
Disable is obvious.
If I set it to Raid the BIOS recognize the drive but the Ubuntu installation halts and the error message indicates that the controller needs to be set to AHCI mode.
If I set it AHCI mode the BIOS will not recognize the drive, however the OS installer does and completes, but at reboot the loading stops with a message that UUID xxxxxx can not be find.
On some Linux distros "demo mode" works but hard drive is not recognized.
I was planning to install multiple Linux variants (I have done it before on older laptops).
Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? My Dell 5310 with Intel 11 Gen chip, just worked in dual boot with Kubuntu 22.04. I often tell uses to change to AHCI and forgot. My system installed with Intel vmd driver with RAID on, but in Windows I did have to have bitlocker & fast startup off. Is drive set to gpt partitioning with an ESP (FAT32 with boot,esp flags)  & are you installing in UEFI mode with UEFI as default boot in UEFI/BIOS settings?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @oldfred. The last time I tried to snaswer something happened and I had to quit. So all the drivers and bios updated, using UEFI mode. Since than I reformatted the harddrive and reinstalled windows 10. I also reduced the size of the Win partition and have a 100 some gigabyte unformatted  partition.

Comment: I would like to install Ubuntu on that partition. I would not mind to boot into bios every time I switch OS. What do I do?

Comment: I typically partition in advance with gparted, but you do not need to. You can use Something else to create partitions. And if new user and only 100GB, the default install of just / (root) is ok. some like separate /home or data partitions. Make sure installer sees Windows partition(s), or else it may overwrite the Windows install. Windows fast startup and bitlocker must be  off during install. If booting from UEFI, you can turn those back on after install.